# jQuery serialize many forms at once and POST

Tags: jquery

I have many forms in a single page.
All the forms have the same class `.wizard_forms`
What I am trying to achieve is that the `ajax POST` function will serialize and `POST` all the inputs from each form at once to the target PHP page.

The problem is that his event should be fired on a click, and obviously `$(this)` is returning the clicked object instead of the forms.

This is what I am doing and obviously it does not work :)
Thanks for any help!

```
$(".save").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("form.wizard_form").each(function() {$(this).serialize()}),
            success: function() {
                $('#publish').modal('show');
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works instead:

```
$(".save").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("form.wizard_form").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $('#publish').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```